# What is the difference between "npm start" and "react-native run-android" deployments?

Tags: android, react-native, npm

I added this new component to my react-native app.

When I do `npm start` on the terminal and reload my app through wireless network (shake the device and touch "reload") onto my android device, one of the components that I have added to my app is not working. But when I connect my android device to my laptop with USB and run `react-native run-android` it works. What is the difference between these two deployments?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make it simple

- npm start: is to start the metro bundler that is required to run any react-native application. The mission of it you can find here: [What is metro bundler in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116811/what-is-metro-bundler-in-react-native)
- react-native run-android: basically it run the npm start command and then build and install the debug apk to the device.

So, when you add new library that is not required linking, you can only re-enter the npm start the reload the app. But when the library need to be link with native code, you need to compile the app again using react-native run-android.