# Compile TypeScript with react-native-typescript-transformer?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, swagger-codegen

Since Expo SDK 31 there is TypeScript support integrated. That’s great.

However, as far as I can tell, it uses `babel-typescript`. For my project, running on Expo SDK 33, I need to use [`react-native-typescript-transformer`](https://github.com/ds300/react-native-typescript-transformer) instead. Is this possible? How I can configure this change?

PS: The reason I need to use `react-native-typescript-transformer` is that I need support for TypeScript namespaces and enums. I use [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate my REST client layer. But all the generators I found use namespaces (and also enums that are not supported either by Babel 7 if I understood well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

Whenever you build and run your React Native project, a packager starts up called Metro. The packager does a few things, including: combining all your Javascript code into a single file, and translates any Javascript code that your device won’t understand - like JSX and TypeScript (credits to [mahdi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906278/1333836)).

To hook up and bypass the `babel-typescript` using `react-native-typescript-transformer` simply create a file in your project root directory called `metro.config.js`. Here's the config:

```
module.exports = {
    transformer: {
        babelTransformerPath: require.resolve(
            'react-native-typescript-transformer',
        ),
    },
};
```

Works on Expo SDK 33 with TypeScript 3.4.5. I managed to finally use `swagger-codegen` to generate my REST client layer!