# How to install react-native-svg-transformer without Expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I've a `react-native 0.64.2` project **without Expo**. Using [this instruction](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer#for-react-native-v057-or-newer--expo-sdk-v3100-or-newer) doesn't work for me, because I don't have the package `metro-config` which means I can't import `getDefaultConfig`.

**metro.config.js**

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Metro != Expo. It is (as well as `metro-config` package) installed as dependency of `@react-native-community/cli` - which is a dependency of `react-native` package. So yes, you definitely do have this package.

Comment: which one did you use to init your project? ```expo-cli``` or ```react-native-cli```?

Comment: @raina77ow Thank you, it worked. I had a bug somewhere else and was mislead by the `Module is ... not in the package.json`-info of my IDE. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @QuangThái Thanks for your reply. I used `expo-cli` but it works now (see my comment above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Metro](https://facebook.github.io/metro/) != [Expo](https://expo.io/). It is a [bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116811/what-is-metro-bundler-in-react-native) used to transform and combine both JavaScript and all the related assets - similar to webpack, but for RN applications.

If you're using `@react-native-community/cli` package, it has both `metro` and `metro-config` as its dependencies, so you should be able to require this package.